# How to hide password in MySqlConnection for user of service WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, password-protection, wcf-security, database-connection

I wrote a service WCF (in c#) for interrogate (only SELECT) my data base MySQL. For a connection I'm using :

```
string MyConnectionString = "Server=11.111.1.11;Database=name_of_database;Uid = login;Pwd=Qsdfd4dfg";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
```

And I'm sur, It's not good to use the name of server, data base, login and password like that but I don't know how can I hide it? (and where?).

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Well, it would usually be in a config file of some sort rather than directly in the source code. Usually, you expect your *services* to be deployed on few machines and the people who have direct access to those machines (such that they can inspect the file system, etc) are usually trusted. (Although there are some options to encrypt config file sections, these are more "belt and braces" to prevent *accidental* exposure)

Comment: So according to you, my password is in the right place?

Comment: You could look in to .net obfuscation if you want to hide values in your code: https://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enAU772AU772&ei=L_CIW4jhA5f6-QblqrDACQ&q=obfuscation+.net&oq=obfuscation+.net&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l8.1585.2353.0.2448.5.5.0.0.0.0.202.384.0j1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.384...0i67k1.0._lnQz5_aV44&safe=active&ssui=on

Comment: Ish. As I say, we prefer it in config rather than code usually. That way the developers don't need to know the production password and it doesn't get stored in source control. The production password is configured when the service is deployed to production. The only people who can read it from there are the accounts with enough permissions to deploy things to production.

Comment: Ok, txh, I misunderstood. And cen you tell me where is this "config" ? It's my file Web.config? If yes, how to tell my MyConnectionString that he has to get the password down there?